# number of vocabulary in gensim is much lower than the ones in training data

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I am using Gensim to train sentences with size 4 and I have 1192 unique words in training dataset. Number of words in model len(model.vocab) is 141 though that does not make sense. Is there any reason for seeing this? How I can change them model to have a key for every word in the training?
model = Word2Vec(windows,min_count=1)

Comment: Could you please provide more code so that it is clear what you are doing?